# Can you help me read the last comment on this deleted question?

Tags: support, comments, deleted-questions

The question was deleted before I had a chance to read the last comment. Since I visit this site only via the app, I have no saved URL from the browser history to give you. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Tip**: To "retrieve" a deleted question to which you do not have a link, you can use an internet search engine, such as Google. Enter the question title and/or parts of the description that you remember into the search box. If the question has been deleted only recently, it would still show up close to the top of the search results.

I didn't have the link to your question either, so I just did the above, and found it in the search results. Since I have [access to moderator tools](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) privilege (colloquially known as the 10K privilege), I could see the [deleted post](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/96588/3192), and here's the last comment you requested:

> @Ooker Because the people working for the recruitment companies are themselves unqualified to judge if a person is qualified for a job or not, so they call pretty much everyone. – Peter 22 hours ago

Until you get the 10K privilege (pedantic: even *afterwards*), you can usually use the 'cache' feature of the search engine to see the [pre-deletion version of the question](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:s1PjIWWBgaAJ:https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/96588/why-would-a-recruiter-call-a-candidate-with-zero-experience-when-surely-there-a), although, as you might expect, the latest comments may not be there.